# how to implement eddystone technology in android app and which android version will support it?

Tags: implementation, android-version, eddystone

Is there any example to implement Eddystone technology in android application, kindly refer the links or own simple example, I also wanna know which version will support it and how to send notification without other device wifi on, (By BLE)

Answer (score 0):

You can see a tutorial for how to build apps with Eddystone [here](http://developer.radiusnetworks.com/2015/07/14/building-apps-with-eddystone.html).  This guide shows you how to detect Eddystone beacons using the free and open source [Android Beacon Library.](http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/)

The minimum Android requirements to detect Eddystone transmissions is Android 4.3 and a device with Bluetooth LE hardware.  To transmit Eddystone advertisements, a device needs at least Android 5.0.